# Make the an id 100% to make 100% wide

Tags: html, css

I have a site here: http://arubacontests.com/

and inside it I have the id #main_area I tried to make it 100% to make it the whole design 100% however it won't let me.

Here's my css:

```
#main_area {
    background: #F4F4F4;
}
```

Feel free to use Chrome's inspect element to check what class do I need to make it 100% wide.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add your HTML & related CSS? I can't visit your URL.

Comment: Add this css .entry-content{ padding:0;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `padding` of `entry-content` in your css

```
.entry-content {
 padding:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `#main_area` there is a div with class `entry-content content`, add the following to it

```
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to remove padding applied to class `.entry-content`. Check [this](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s334/sh/f61199d1-3bcc-4a17-ac8f-d44cf1bbd00f/7b74c9b69382d301ad87a46f7742b9fa)